# python 2.7 Tkinter how to pass an array in another function

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, toplevel

with a button (envoi) I open a new window and write values of elements in an array (choices). After i close this window and call a function (window2).
I want to read choices in this function
If i write print choices.get(), I have an error : global name 'choices' is not defined

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
group = LabelFrame(root, text=" 1. Paramètrage: ")

group.grid(row=0, columnspan=5, sticky='W', \
          padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

dropVar2=StringVar()
dropVar2.set("----")
opt3 = OptionMenu(group, dropVar2, '----', 'Pondéraux', 'Atomiques')
opt3.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=7, sticky='WE', padx=5, pady=2)

def state():
    if dropVar2.get()=='Atomiques':
        winE=Toplevel(root)
        group = LabelFrame(winE, text="Pourcentages atomiques", padx=5,pady=5)
        group.pack(padx=25, pady=25)

        entries = []
        j = 0
        choices = ['C', 'Ni', 'Co', 'Fe', 'Cr', 'Al', 'Ti', 'Ta', 'Nb',
               'Hf', 'V', 'Re', 'Mo', 'W', 'B', 'Zr', 'Mg', 'Y']
        while j < len(choices) :
            valeurOneLabel = Label(group, text=choices[j])
            valeurOneLabel.grid(row=j+1, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='WE', padx=5, pady=2)
            en = Entry(group, text="")
            en.grid(row=j+1, column=1)
            entries.append(en)
            j+=1
        for s in range(len(choices)):
            choices[s] = entries[s]

        exitButton = Button(winE, text = 'Close', command = lambda:  window2(winE)).pack()


def window2(winE):
    winA=Toplevel(root)
    winA.geometry('400x600+600+50')
    print choices.get()
    winE.destroy()

Button(group, text='envoi', command = state).grid(row=5, column=0)




root.geometry("450x350+100+100")
root.title("Développement d'alliages")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The `choices` list is local to the `state` function, so `window2` can't see it. You could make `choices` a global, that way both functions will be able to access it, and they won't need to use the `global` directive if they don't reassign the `choices` name. But it would better to put you GUI into a class and make `choices` an attribute so that it can be easily accessed anywhere in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [PM 2Ring](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4014959/pm-2ring) has stated above `choices` is a variable local to `state()`, this means that `window2()` doesn't know about any `list` called `choices`.

There are a few solutions:

First and possibly the least recommended, you could make `choices` a global variable which would be accessible from anywhere. This could lead to naming conflicts and can make it more frustrating to come back and change this code later.

Second, when you declare the `Button` widget which calls `window2()` you could add `choices` as a parameter to be passed over to the function.

Thirdly and personally the most recommended, you could rewrite your GUI to include a `class` which would allow you to have variables local to the class that can be accessed by any function.